# How to deploy a dart app as a html file or as a folder containing an html file that someone can run offline

Tags: dart, dart2js

Can I can distribute a dart application to a client as a folder or html file so it can be run by clicking the html file to run the app offline?

I can run my dart app that resides on my local 127.0.0.1 but not by clicking the html file in the web directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that the app was converted to Javascript before you deploy it.  Dart itself cannot run on a random person's computer.  However, Dart converted to Javascript can.  If you go to the Tools menu in Dart Editor there is an option for "Generate Javascript".